# Understanding the Implication of Being Abelian of A Quotient Group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory, abelian-groups

So far I have reached (and **understood**) to the point where it is proved that $\text{Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$ is a normal group in my study of theorem 2 of the article "[Galois for beginners](http://www.math.jhu.edu/~smahanta/Teaching/Spring10/Stillwell.pdf)" by John Stillwell (**BTW,** I had to use a lemma  which is not mentioned explicitly in the proof, see postscript 1). This is half of the theorem.  The next line is

> > so it now remains to check that $\text{Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$ is abelian.

And I **understand** how it is proved in the following part of the proof. However, I **don't understand**, how being $\text{Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$ abelian implies, ${\rm Gal}(E/B)/{\rm Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$ is abelian (the remaining part of theorem 2).

Can anyone please explain how being $\text{Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$ abelian implies, $\text{Gal}(E/B)/\text{Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$ is abelian? Thanks.

See the proof below-

[image]

**Postscript :**

1.
LEMMA 2.7.3:    If $\phi$ is a homomorphism of $G$ into $\bar G$ with kernel $K$, then $K $is a
normal subgroup of $G$, from Topics in Algebra by I .N. Herstein .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first rule of the proof is:

*By the homomorphism theorem for groups, it suffices to find a homomorphism of ${\rm Gal}(E/B)$ with kernel ${\rm Gal}(E/B(\alpha)$ into an abelian group.*

It is then proved that the map $\cdot|_{B(\alpha)}$ in ${\rm Gal}(E/B)$ has kernel ${\rm Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$.

Then he says:

*[..] This also implies that $\cdot|_{B(\alpha)}$ maps ${\rm Gal}(E/B)$ into ${\rm Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$, so it now remains to check that ${\rm Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$ is abelian.*

The homomorphism theorem (or first isomorphism theorem) says that if $\phi:G\to H$ is a group homomorphism with kernel $K$, then $G/K\cong \phi(G)$. If $H$ is abelian, then $\phi(G)$ is abelian.

In this case, we have $\cdot |_{B(\alpha)}:{\rm Gal}(E/B)\to {\rm Gal}(B(\alpha)/B)$ with kernel ${\rm Gal}(E/B(\alpha))$.

Comment: So, there are 2 implicit implications, and for a beginner I need to make those explicit, so plz confirm below 2 statements: 

1. If $H$ is abelian, then $\phi(G)$ is abelian **because** $\phi(G)$ is a subgroup of  abelian group $H$.

2. $G/K$ is abelian **since**  $\phi(G)$ is abeleian and $G/K$ has *same structure* to a abelian group, i.e. $G/K\cong \phi(G)$
... are these 2 statements correct?

Comment: 1. Yes, a subgroup of an abelian group is abelian. 2. Yes, a group isomorphic to an abelian group is abelian. (Both statements are more or less trivial, if they are not to you, it is a good exercise to prove them.)

Comment: I would encourage you to learn group theory before learning Galois theory :)